# Building bicubic coons patch from four boundary curves

Tags: math, graphics, surface

I want to create s coons patch surface from four boundary curves s1(u), s2(u) q1(v), q2(v)

I know that equations are the following (added screenshots from a presentation):

[image]

[image]

[image]

There are a few parts of the equations that are not fully understand and i did not find any good explanation:

1. In s1(u,v) what is the meaning of p1v(u) and p2v(u)? same goes for q1u(v) and q2u(v) in s2(u,v).
2. In the A matrix, what is the meaning of A00(u,v)..A11(u,v). What would be the value of these parameters if p1,p2 are only functions of u (and not v) and q1,q2 are only function of v.

I would appreciate any help on this issue.

Comment: can you paste a link to the presentation, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically they have used superscripts to denote derivatives or partial derivatives.

As we are building bi-cubic coons patches we will be using [Cubic Hermite splines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline). These require both the positions and the tangents as inputs. So for the first edge P<sub>1</sub>(u) is the parametrisation of the curve and P<sub>1</sub><sup>v</sup>(u) is the tangent across the edge. Any point in a surface actually has two tangents the other being P<sub>1</sub><sup>u</sup>(u) along the edge which is just dP<sub>1</sub>(u) / du.

For the A matrix, this takes the four corner points of the patches and the derivatives. For the point A<sub>00</sub> it uses the two first derivatives ∂S / ∂u = A<sub>00</sub><sup>u</sup> and ∂S / ∂v  = A<sub>00</sub><sup>u</sup> and one of the second derivatives ∂<sup>2</sup>S / ∂u ∂v = A<sub>00</sub><sup>uv</sup>. (I've used S for for the function defining the surface here). As the derivatives of the curves along the edges must match the derivatives at the corners we have some further conditions

- A<sub>00</sub><sup>u</sup> = ∂S / ∂u = P<sub>1</sub><sup>u</sup>(0) = Q<sub>1</sub><sup>u</sup>(0) = dP<sub>1</sub> / du (0)
- A<sub>00</sub><sup>v</sup> = ∂S / ∂v = P<sub>1</sub><sup>v</sup>(0) = Q<sub>1</sub><sup>v</sup>(0) = dQ<sub>1</sub> / dv (0)
- A<sub>00</sub><sup>uv</sup> = ∂<sup>2</sup>S / ∂u∂v = ∂P<sub>1</sub><sup>v</sup>/∂u (0) = ∂Q<sub>1</sub><sup>u</sup>/∂u (0)